# Firestore PITR returns Invalid Transaction

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Today was the day I needed to recover the initial version of an updated document, as described in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-pitr#client-libraries). I know from Firestore that the document was created on `September 10, 2023 at 16:19:17 GMT ({ _seconds: 1694362757, _nanoseconds: 397127000 })`

Running the example from the documentation returns an error when trying with any `readTime` earlier than `1694390000 (September 10, 23:53:20 GMT)`:

> Invalid transaction. Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient

```js
const ref = db.collection('rentals').doc('q5MsBad7ZKM9jP5FbZbJ')

const doc = await db.runTransaction(
  transaction => transaction.get(ref),
  {readOnly: true, readTime: new Timestamp(1694362757, 397127000)}
)
```

Any clue what's wrong? GCS specifies earliest data point is 4th of September, which is correct, since it is only available for 7 days. As a last resort, I'd try exporting the DB at that specific point in time but it is gigantic with the `logs` table having millions of entries .. hoping that it would return the document as it was when created.

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I know it is a few days late, but the solution to your problem is to make sure that the timestamp you are using is at a whole minute granularity. This tripped me up for quite a while at first as well.
From the docs
"Make sure that the timestamp you specify is a whole minute timestamp within the past hour, but not earlier than the earliestVersionTime. If data no longer exists at the specified timestamp, an error is generated."
https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/use-pitr

Comment: Yep, thanks for the input. I forgot to add a solution here myself. Firebase Support came through quite quick on it after sending them all de nitty gritty.